# Remaining Balance of debit - credit using eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a client database with transactions.
Each transaction has 2 sql columns, DEBIT and CREDIT. Both may be filled in or just one.

Using eloquent, what i want is the SUM of DEBIT - SUM OF CREDIT so i can get his balance.

Transaction schema look like this:

```
Schema::create('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');
          $table->datetime('datestamp')->nullable();;
          $table->text('reason')->nullable();;
          $table->decimal('debit')->default(0);
          $table->decimal('credit')->default(0);

          $table->integer('customerId')->unsigned();
          $table->foreign('customerId')->references('id')->on('customers');

          $table->boolean('isDeleted')->default(0);
          $table->timestamps();
      });
```

My Customer Model look like this:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class customer extends Model
{
    public function transaction()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\transaction','customerId','id')->where("isDeleted",0)->orderBy('datestamp');
    }

}
```

My transaction model looks like this:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class transaction extends Model
{
    public function balance()
    {
        // problem is that i dont know how to get only for specific customer
        $debit = transaction::sum('debit');
        $credit = transaction::sum('credit');
        return $debit-credit; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You first need a `customer` object so you can reference their transactions through the relationship you've created:

```
$customer = customer::find(1);

$transactions = $customer->transactions;

$balance = $transactions->sum(function($trans){
    return $trans->debit - $trans->credit;
});
```

To place this in the `customer` model is simple:

```
class customer extends Model
{
    public function transaction()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\transaction','customerId','id')->where("isDeleted",0)->orderBy('datestamp');
    }

    public function getBalanceAttribute(){

        return $this->transactions->sum(function($trans){

            return $trans->debit - $trans->credit;

        });
    }
}
```

Now you can access the balance of a customer just by using `$customer->balance`

Comment: Thank you. Your solution though seems to live inside a controller and i want to place it inside the model. Else I have to do your solution for each customer in a loop.

Comment: @SimosFasouliotis simple adjustment to place this in a customer model, see edit

Comment: I dont understand. in the customer model exists getBalanceAttribute, but you advise to get the balance by doing $customer->balance; is it typo or something i dont understand ?

Comment: @SimosFasouliotis that is a laravel trick to make it easier.  if you have a function called `->getFooAttribute()` you can just use `->foo`. Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I did try the code, but unfortunatelly $customers (each) does not containt a balance attribute. I'm using a $customers = customer::where('isDeleted',0)->get(); I tried adding ->with('balance') but produces error. Any idea?

Comment: Adding protected $appends = array('balance'); fixed the problem. if you want add this to your answer so i can mark as accepted.